# Grails controller search criteria with list

Tags: grails

I need to do a search based on various criteria.

1. if a name contains the specified string.
2. if the name contains the specified string and a string from a list.
3. if the name contains one of the strings from a list.

I have the following code but it doesn't work. How bad is this code?

```
def taskList = Object.createCriteria().list(params) {
if (params.query) {
    ilike("name", "%${params.query}%")
}
if (params.nameList) {
    params.nameList.split("&").each {
            or {
              ilike("name", "%${it}$%")
            }
    }
    }
```

The result is empty for use cases 2 & 3. What am I doing wrong? How should I do it?

Cheers

Comment: Are the two $-signs intentional in "%${it}$%"?

Comment: No to the two dollar signs. Typing error on my part. The lines should really be ilike("name", "%${it}%")

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `in` operator for 3. case

```
list{
  or{
    if( params.query ) ilike "name", "%${params.query}%"
    if( params.nameList ) 'in' 'name', params.nameList.split("&")
  }
}
```

Comment: Rats. Did not work. Tried it with one and two names in the list and it did not work for either.

Comment: oh, `or{}` is missing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def taskList = Object.createCriteria().list(params) {
    def names = []
    if(params.nameList){
       names = nameList.split("&")
    }
    or{
        if (params.query){ilike("name", "%${params.query}%")}
        and{
            if (params.query){ilike("name", "%${params.query}%")}
            if(names){'in'('name', names)}
        }
        if (names) {
            names.each {name->
                or {
                  ilike("name", "%$name$%")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Untested*, but can you try with above. I would rather go with an HQL to achieve what you needed.